# Get the LatLng of the newly dragged direction using directions_changed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to get the LatLng when I dragged the directions?

for example, in marker we can get the LatLng by
`google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
        var latLng = event.latLng;
 });`

Is it possible to make like this?

```
directionDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function (event) {
    addWaypoint(event.latLng);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though `directions_changed` event handler does not accept any parameters, the location of newly dragged direction could be extracted from [Directions Service response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult), for example from `via_waypoints` property of `google.maps.DirectionsLeg` object:

> Type:  Array
>
> An array of waypoints along this leg that were not specified in the
>   original request, either as a result of a user dragging the polyline
>   or selecting an alternate route.

For example:

```
renderer.addListener('directions_changed', function (e) {
    var result = renderer.getDirections();
    var wayPoint = result.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoint[0]; //get waypoint as a result of a user dragging
    console.log(wayPoint.location.toString());    
});
```

**Example**

```js
var map;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.0970915, -75.7199607),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var origin = "New York County, New York", destination = "Toronto, Ontario, Canada";
    displayRoute(directionsService, origin, destination);

});

function displayRoute(directionsService, origin, destination) {
    var request = {
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            renderResponse(response);
        }
        else
            alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
    });
}

//draws the route on the map and adds draggable listener
function renderResponse(result) {
    var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        zoom: 4,
        draggable: true,
        map: map,
        directions: result
    });
    printRouteInfo(result);

    renderer.addListener('directions_changed', function (e) {
        printRouteInfo(renderer.getDirections());
    });
}

function printRouteInfo(result) { 
    if(result.routes.length > 0 && result.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoint.length > 0) {
        var wayPoint = result.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoint[0];
        //console.log(wayPoint.location.toString());    
        document.getElementById('routeInfo').innerHTML = 'Location:' +  wayPoint.location.toString();            
    }
}
```

```css
#map_div {
   height: 600px;
   float: left;
   width: 63%;
}
#right-panel {
        float: right;
        width: 34%;
        height: 100%;
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select, #right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_div"></div>
     <div id="right-panel">
     <div id='routeInfo'></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/v65re5w4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your map looks as it does [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable) at google with a few exceptions:

```
function initMap(){
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -24.345, lng: 134.46}  // Australia.
  });
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
  });
  directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
  });
  displayRoute('Perth, WA', 'Sydney, NSW', directionsService, directionsDisplay);
}
function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display){
  service.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    waypoints: [{location: 'Cocklebiddy, WA'}, {location: 'Broken Hill, NSW'}],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  avoidTolls: true
  }, function(response, status){
    if(status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      display.setDirections(response);
    }
    else{
      alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
function computeTotalDistance(result){
  var total = 0, myroute = result.routes[0];
  for(var i=0,l=myroute.legs.length; i<l; i++){
    total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
  }
  for(var i=0,l=myroute.overview_path.length; i<l; i++){
    // should be a LatLng object at each iteration
    console.log(myroute.overview_path[i]);
  }
  total = total / 1000;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
}
```

Comment: Sir help me. I'm getting this error TypeError: rts.waypoint_order is undefined